# WCF sending Event to Client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, events

I have an application (server) and a client connected by WCF over named pipes (all .NET 4.0). All works fine. Both calling methods from client to server and server to client (callbacks) work fine. Now, how do I simply send an event from the server to the client?

What I try to accomplish is:

- Client calls a long term method on the server that returns immediately
- When server is ready processing it sends an Event to the client
- The client can then call a method on the server to get the results

How do I do this in a clean manner?

Comment: I always have one client and one server, so I think a publish/subscribe implementation might be overkill?

Comment: The [duplex services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) scenario seems like a fit for your requirement, I'm not sure if NamedPipes supports duplex communication, but [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) suggests it does.

Comment: @Jeroen what about when the event that the server will publish it got it on a background thread? In that case `OperationContext.Current` will be **null** and I won't be able to publish that event to the client.

Comment: @JobaDiniz Oh my... my comment was from 2012. If you have a new / follow-up question I suggest formulating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at doing it asynchronously: [How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). (*It's a bit much code to paste here, so I'll just leave the link.*)

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous WCF call is the way to go if you want to be simpler. In .NET 4.0 there is the `async` keyword in there. Or you can wait for a certain time and then call the server function to see if the file is ready. To be sure I would use async, to be simpler and fast use polling.